# ShouldOverrideUrlLoading not called after clicking on a link in a webpage loaded with LoadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

The method ShouldOverrideUrlLoading in my custom webview client is not called when i click on a link inside html loaded in the webview with webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, body, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

So as a result i'm getting a blank page :(

How can i intercept click events or is there any way that shouldoverrideurloading can be called?

class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public delegate void PageLoaded();
            public event PageLoaded PageLoadedEvent;

```
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl (url);
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnPageStarted (WebView view, string url, Android.Graphics.Bitmap favicon)
        {
            base.OnPageStarted (view, url, favicon);

        }

        public override void OnPageFinished (WebView view, string url)
        {
            if(PageLoadedEvent != null)
            {
                PageLoadedEvent ();
            }
            base.OnPageFinished (view, url);

        }

        public override void OnReceivedError (WebView view, ClientError errorCode, string description, string failingUrl)
        {
            base.OnReceivedError (view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs) "If you loaded the page by calling loadData() or loadDataWithBaseURL() with an invalid or null base URL, then you will not receive the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() callback for this type of link on the page." You should change your base URL  when calling LoadDataWithBaseURL() from null to a valid URL.